# How to add a redirection for additional domain

Tags: apache2.2

I have a server with the following virtual host defined :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /dev/null
  ServerName www.originaldomain.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.)?originaldomain.com
  ReWriteRule ^.*$ http://www.destinationdomain.com [L,QSA,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

This successfully redirects www.originaldomain.com and originaldomain.com to www.destinationdomain.com.

However I now to additionally redirect www.originaldomain2.com and originaldomain2.com to destinationdomain.com.  As an Apache novice I am unsure how best to achieve this.  Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ServerAlias for each of your new domains.

```
ServerAlias www.originaldomain2.com
ServerAlias originaldomain2.com
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, but I'm afraid it doesn't work.  Won't the Rewrite condition fail when using the aliases ?